# Regex: Matching anything after a certain group and up to empty line

Tags: regex

This has been bugging me.

I want to capture from, e.g.:

> Skills:
> Java
> Motorboating
> Kite-crafting
> C++
> Sleeping
>
> Training:
> Uni of Pluto
> College of Saturn
> School of Venus

but only what comes **after** "Skills:" **up to** the first empty line before "Training:"

So far I've managed to use
`(?<=Skills\:)[\n\r](.*)[\n\r]`

But the definition of an empty line at the end of the regex has been making me mad. Some help, please?

Comment: Did any of the posted answers work out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match all lines that are not empty after Skills. If there can also be spaces at the start of the string before matching the first character:

```
(?<=Skills:)(?:\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\S.*)+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=Skills:)` Assert `Skills:` directly to the left
- `(?:` non capture group

  - `\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\S.*` Match a newline, optional spaces without a newline. Then match a non whitespace char and the rest of the line.
- `)+` Repeat 1+ times to prevent an empty match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zklccI/1)

Or with a match instead of a lookbehind and a capture group:

```
\bSkills:((?:\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*\S.*)+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HQlU41/1)

Answer (score 0):

This one should work for you

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qyCNxv/1)

```
(?<=Skills\:\n)([^\n]+\n)*
```

Basically match at least one non-newline character on each line.